# RESTful API over Git repository

Tags: git, rest, spring-boot

I want to host a Git remote repository of my own and then expose it over a REST API from my application(spring boot). My question is how would the clone/fork etc would work ? 
Is it techincally feasible to transfer all the files/content in the repository over an Http response when a client calls my clone API ? 
Has anyone achieved this and what would be the best approach ?

Comment: What do you think a RESTful API would accomplish? REST doesn't mean HTTP - git already works over HTTP. Creating a different endpoint would serve no purpose

Answer (score 0):

You don't wish to create something like Github by yourself, do you? :)

But addressing your specific question, the clone/fork should obviously NOT  transfer files with Http response/request, but instead should send to the server which exposes the REST API something like the HTTP request `POST cloneRepository` with the HTTP parameter `repositoryName` (set to the repository name to be cloned), which would be then processed by a Spring MVC controller, which would in turn launch Git commands on the server which hosts Git repositories.

Comment: Or you could use CGI and [git-http-backend](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend).

Comment: Thanks. Infact I am already hosting Git a remote repository on my server in addition to my spring boot application . And from my application I need to manage this repository. Like when I clone a repo in my application(from UI) , I want the git clone to be performed by my application which would transfer the repo content to the client . Cloning it again on the server is something which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @manubhat If I now understand correctly (it seems that I misunderstood your question), you should follow the suggestion of  Panagiotis Kanavos Perhaps also http://www.parallelsymmetry.com/howto/git.jsp might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

GitRows provides a namespace-based API for obtaining data from a git repo, (github/gitlab) and can be modified for personal use.

https://gitrows.com/
https://github.com/gitrows/gitrows

Sample:

> `curl -X GET 'https://api.gitrows.com/@github/gitrows/data/iris.json'`